# Use external claims form OpenId server

Tags: asp.net-core, openid, keycloak

I'm trying to use Keycloak as an OpenId server for my ASP.Net core app.

It's almost ok. The user gets authorized (passes through `[Authorize]` attribute), but his claims are empty.

My configuration:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = "cookie"; })
    .AddCookie("cookie")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
      options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/";
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      options.ClientId = "test-client";
      options.ClientSecret = "ee117d6d-25c9-4317-83a0-54c2f252aa89";
      options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
      options.SaveTokens = true;
      options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/SignOut";
      options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "Redirect-here";
      options.ResponseType = "code";
    });
```

A controller action which works fine (gets authorized):

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult About()
{
  ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

  return View();
}
```

A controller action which is unauthorized (as it requires a role):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public IActionResult About()
{
  ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

  return View();
}
```

AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
  if (remoteError != null)
  {
    ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
  }
  var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); // it has claims
  if (info == null)
  {
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
  }

  var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

  if (result.Succeeded)
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
  }
  if (result.IsLockedOut)
  {
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
  }
  else
  {
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
    var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Email = email });
  }
}
```

`info` objct from the snippet above has the claims, especially roles claims:

[image]

But when I'm logged in and try to see the roles and clams, the are emtpy:

```
var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User); // user is found
var roles = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user); // empty
var claims = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user); //empty
```

So it looks like Keycloak is doing everything fine, but my app has problems consuming the claims.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the authentication provider so it knows which claim type to use for roles.

You can configure it as follows:

```
services.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    ...

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        RoleClaimType = "user_roles"; // or "user_realm_roles"?
    };
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Claims (including roles) are not copied from `ExternalLoginInfo`. Could you provide the rest of the `AddOpenIdConnect` implementation?

Comment: The rest is what you've already implemented.  Have you got two applications here...one Identity Server, one Web App?

Comment: No, just the minimal client app and Keycloak itself as identity server. The root of the problem is that claims (all of the claims, not just roles) form Keycloak token are ignored by Identity.

Comment: Take a look at `options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived` (called after login) in the OpenIdConnectOptions...you can create a handler which allows you to access the claims from Keycloak and add a ClaimsIdentity to the Principal that uses the correct role claim type.

Comment: I added it like so: `context.HttpContext.User.AddIdentity((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity);` but in the next request, the Keycloak identity disappears form HttpContext. What should I do to keep it in the HttpContext until user logs out?

Comment: You need to add a new ClaimsIdentity to `context.Principal`.  You need to use the constructor that allows you to set the `RoleClaimType` property.